# What is react component in typescript inteface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

In typescript interface, we can define, like :

```
export interface ViewContainerProps {
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  children?: React.ReactNode
  aString:string
  aNumber:number
}
```

I want to write a custom top-level `<View>`, to cover all screen, it look like this:

```
const VIEW_CONTAINER: ViewStyle = {
  width: windowWidth,
  height: windowHeight,
};
export interface ViewContainerProps {
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  children?: React.ReactNode ///no , something wrong
}
export const ViewContainer = (props: ViewContainerProps) => {
  const {style, children} = props;
  return <View style={[style, VIEW_CONTAINER]}>{children}</View>;
};
```

And i want to children return `React component` to interact and do anything that a react component do, what type of React can i put in typescript interface? I read some docs , say that React.reactNode  `a light, stateless, immutable, virtual representation of a DOM node`, feel like it not what i want when create top-level components that wrap all child components

Please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.ReactNode` is the correct type. One way to be sure of that is by looking at the build in type for functional components `React.FC`, you can see that it types the `children` prop as `React.ReactNode`.

Rather than adding the children prop yourself, you should use `React.FC` for your component:

```
import React from "react"

export interface ViewContainerProps {
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
}

export const ViewContainer: React.FC<ViewContainerProps> = (props) => {
  const { style, children } = props;
  return <View style={[style, VIEW_CONTAINER]}>{children}</View>;
};
```

Comment: So i can use React.ReactNode? Is that okey, that i use React.ReactNode, because it will containt all my app action and things, like sync to sever or re-render, in nutshell , react-things, so it sound great when i can use React.ReactNode, thank for your answer, btw

Answer (score 1):

You can use React.FunctionComponent or React.FC

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

export const ViewContainer: FC = (props: ViewContainerProps) => {
  const {style, children} = props;
  return <View style={[style, VIEW_CONTAINER]}>{children}</View>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i will use React.FC